# Tunnelling TCP to database (ms-Sql) through corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, tcp, tunneling

**What I know.**

- I have a ms sql in Internet, let say *hostDB*:1433
- I have a corporate proxy *ipProxy*:8080

  - /bin/nc -z -v -w 1 -x *ipProxy*:8080 -X connect *hostDB* 1433
  - Connection to *hostDB*  1433 port [tcp/ms-sql-s] succeeded!
- Our infrastruture (in intranet) is managed by kubernetes, so I'm free to read any solution.

**What I need.**

I need to reach this database from our intranet through this proxy, that seems it should work.

**What I tried.**

- netcat tunnel
- nginx proxy reverse (stream)
- coding directly in our application but the library doesn't support proxys connections.

I would love if I could run a docker img that make this tunnel, then my app will connect to this container as localhost:1433

I read something related iptables, but I don't know anything related router settings.

Comment: I don't think you can use an HTTP proxy for non http communications.